# How to use mod rewrite to redirect URL?

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I'm wanting to redirect URL that not end with to `slash` to ending with `slash`.
note: *.htaccess is in `mysite` directory*

**.htaccess**

```
<need help here>
```

**Not want URL**

```
http://localhost/mysite/index.php
http://localhost/mysite/blog
http://localhost/mysite/blog/110084
```

**Desired URL**

```
http://localhost/mysite/
http://localhost/mysite/blog/
http://localhost/mysite/blog/110084/
```

Many thanks.

Comment: Unclear what your question is. What is the problem with your current rules?

Comment: Please include details of what is wrong with the rules you've written so far, SO is for asking questions about specific problems not a code writing service.  Providing some example URLs that are not rewritten correctly with your current rules would make this an actual question

Comment: It not about rules, but it about redirection that redirect URL not ending to `slash` to ending with `slash` for example: `mysite` -> `mysite/` or `mysite/blog` -> `mysite/blog/`.

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /Application
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|table-images|robots\.txt|styles|js|uploads)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

Comment: Try to add a brief explanation of what your code does.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this rule as **very first rule** just below `RewriteEngine On` line to add trailing slash for non-file:

```
# add a trailing slash to directories
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*?[^/])$ %{REQUEST_URI}/ [L,R=302]
```